# MVC kendo timepicker value null when i edit kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have using inline editing in mvc datagrid. when i select edit for editing record TimePicker value is null.

```
**In Grid**             
 columns.Bound(p=>p.TimeRequired).EditorTemplateName("GridTimePicker").Title("Time");**     

 **Editor Template (GridTimePicker.cshtml):**          
  @model DateTime?      
  @(                            
   Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m=>m).Name("GridTimePicker").Interval(15)    
   )
```

how to solve this problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should not set the `Name()` when using `TimePickerFor`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m=>m).Interval(15))
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: when i edit the grid the timepicker set the textbox and set the long datetime value format if i do not use the name in timepicker e.g Mon Jan 1 05:30:00 UTC+0530 1

Answer (score 0):

*******Editor Template****************

```
@model DateTime?
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("TimeRequired") //name should be same as property
    .Value(Model == null ? DateTime.Now.Date : ((DateTime)@Model).Date)
)
```

************************Grid******************

```
 // will print the date in "28/01/2014" style...
    columns.Bound(p=>p.TimeRequired).EditorTemplateName("GridTimePicker").Title("Time")
    .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(TimeRequired,'d') #")
```

regards

## Shaz

Comment: i have tried your code in my project but when i edit the grid timepicker set full datetime string format value in textbox. e.g Fri Feb 28 15:45:00 UTC+0530 2014

Comment: is TimeRequired is DateTime field..?? if it is a datetime then you do'nt need a editor template kendo grid does that automatically for you ....and you can set the dataannotations for you model defining it..... [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Comment: yes it is a datetime field.. i have set data annotations in model but still not solved.Text box appear and set long datetime string format value when i edit the grid..

Comment: are you using Client binding or server binding..??? please check you have .Ajax() enables in your Grid Markup... or .Server() if you are using .Ajax() --->ClientTemplate should work otherwise incase of .Server()--->.Template(@<text> @item.TimeRequired.toString("dd/MM/yyyy") <text>)